# Saving an EditText (textfield) value in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

In other words. I'd like to create editable textfield in fragment, wich after close or stop of app would be saved. But there's something wrong in line with `return notatki;` I already have this:

```
public class DetailFragment2 extends Fragment {

    private EditText notatki;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");


    }     
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, parent, false);
        EditText notatki = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", ""));
        return notatki;
    }  
    @Override
    public void onStop( ){
        super.onStop();
        if(notatki.getText() != null) {
            SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("value", notatki.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

When I change `return notatki;` to `return view;` it works till the stop of app, when I wanted to save content of editText but it isnt saving anything.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Do you have a logcat print for us?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are setting null to your EditText `notatki` at:

```
notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", "raz dwa trzy"));
```

And thus you have a NPE at `onStop()` with:

```
notatki.getText().toString()
```

To solve this change your onStop() method to:

```
public void onStop( ){
    super.onStop();
    if(notatki.getText() != null) {
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("value", notatki.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still it doesn't work. I think it could be something in `onCreateView` because at first I thought I should use `return notatki;`, but it didn't work

Comment: and Im not certain if I can use `(settings.getString("value", ""));` in a fragment

Comment: That should work. At least your error must be changed. BTW you can use that. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)